# Oracle PL/SQL number to_char ignores 0's even when decimal part exist

Tags: sql, oracle

Im using the following code to convert a number(38,2) to the format "XXX.XXX.XXX,XX":

```
TO_CHAR(number, '999G999G999G999G999G999G999D99')
```

Although, when the number is `0` or `0.XX` the 0 is eaten up :

```
Input: 0
Result: ",00"
Expected Result: "0,00"

Input: 0.23
Result: ",23"
Expected Result: "0,23"
```

Why does this happen, is there a way of solving this without manipulating the result string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `0` instead of `9`

```
TO_CHAR(0.00, '999G999G999G999G999G999G990D99')
```

`0` ensures that if there is no digit in that place it'll display 0.